# scipy has no attribute signal

Tags: python, scipy

I have a file which imports a function from another file, like shown below.

**file1.py:**

```
# import scipy.signal
import file2

file2.foo()
```

**file2.py:**

```
import scipy


def foo():
    scipy.signal.butter(2, 0.01, 'lowpass', analog=False)
```

When I run file1.py I get the following error:

> File "file2.py", line 5, in foo
> scipy.signal.butter(2, 0.01, 'lowpass', analog=False)
> AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'signal'

However, when I uncomment line 1 from **file1.py** (`import scipy.signal`) the error disappears. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With scipy, you need to import the submodule directly with either `import scipy.signal` or `from scipy import signal`. Many submodule won't work if you just import scipy. You can read about the scipy api [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/)